# Access the tkinter window behind a turtle program with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-turtle

I have a turtle application and I want to hide the user's mouse cursor. I know how to do this with a tkinter window so I tried to create a tkinter window and hide the cursor but it is only hidden when I hover over that window, not the turtle window. So I need a way to access the tkinter window behind my turtle app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the turtle canvas itself and change its cursor settings:

```
c = turtle.getcanvas()
c.config(cursor="none")
```